# What's the difference between a clustering and bin packing problem?

Tags: cluster-analysis, bin, packing

When I look at the mathematical model for clustering and bin packing I can't see the difference between them as the variables and constraints are the same ( the first considers the distance between nodes and the 2nd their weight)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Clustering is much broader. Your view is likely biased by an optimization perspective.

Consider the famous clustering algorithm [DBSCAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN). Does it still look like bin packing to you? It's actual based on connected components of a graph, and the main thing is that you don't want to build the entire graph because of runtime and computation cost. For an optimization problem that would mean not even writing down the entire problem, because it has too many variables.